# How to install splunkclient for Windows

Tags: python-3.x, splunk, splunk-sdk

I am trying to connect to my splunk server via Python on my WIndows laptop.

I downloaded splunklib and splunk-sdk. However, when I run

```
import splunklib.client as client
```

I get an error of

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'splunklib.client'; 'splunklib' is not a package
```

Any ideas on why this is occurring and suggestions on to how to fix this or the best way to access Splunk via Python?

Answer (score 1):

Did you properly install the splunk-sdk? You would normally use something like `pip` to install it.

```
pip install splunk-sdk
```

Alternatively, you can install it into the `PYTHONPATH`

Refer to
https://dev.splunk.com/enterprise/docs/python/sdk-python/gettingstartedpython/installsdkpython/

Answer (score 0):

Windows requires a manual setup of the SDK.

1. Download the [Splunk Software Development Kit for Python](https://github.com/splunk/splunk-sdk-python) as a zip file.
2. Unzip the zip file into the same directory as your program source.
3. Add the following line to your source code before `import splunklib.client as client`:

   `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "splunk-sdk-python-master"))`

Another option is to unzip the sdk to another folder and specify the absolute path in the `sys.path.insert()`.